# Trouble upgrading R on Debian 10 (buster) running on a Lenovo Chromebook

Tags: r, debian, chromebook, debian-buster

I have a new Lenovo Chromebook which comes with a Debian 10 (buster) app. It's an app that runs linux in a terminal. I am trying to install the newest version of the statistical software R (4.0.3) but it keeps reverting to version 3.5.2. I get the following errors and no matter how many times I uninstall and reinstall r-base and r-base-core, it won't let me install 4.X.X. I've tried this fix: https://www.charlesbordet.com/en/how...0-0-on-debian/ but I still get the errors below. Any advice would be most appreciated!

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1~bustercran.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.3-1~bustercran.0) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `r-base-core` from [`buster-cran40`](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/buster-cran40/) (`r-base-html` will be installed as dependency).

make sure to have the following line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t buster-cran40  r-base-core
sudo apt install -t buster-cran40  r-base
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer for chromebooks, but if you are using regular `Debian Stable (currently Buster, Debian 10`), the currently used version of `GNU R` is [3.5](https://packages.debian.org/buster/r-base). There are two main ways to solve this: either use [backports](https://backports.debian.org/) or [run a container with a newer version of `GNU R`, as e.g. shown in this video by Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIjWirNma-8).